# Word wrap on non-alphabetical character

Tags: css, word-wrap

I want to break my strings like this, using css:

*Input:*

```
this,is,a,bad,punctuaction,example.
```

*Output:*

```
this,is,a,bad,
punctuation,
example.
```

Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes possible if you wrap each word in a `span` element as shown in the below example:

**HTML**

```
<div><span>this,</span><span>is,</span><span>a,</span><span>bad,</span>
<span>punctuation,</span><span>example.</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div span {
    float: left;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jF3ga/2/)**

otherwise, you need to look in to javascript.

**JS** (*example*):

```
var div = document.getElementById('main');
div.innerHTML = "<span>" + div.innerHTML.split(",").join(",</span><span>") + "</span>";
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jF3ga/)**

Answer (score 1):

In 2018, this can be done with CSS:

```
.dont-break-out {
  /* These are technically the same, but use both */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  /* This is the dangerous one in WebKit, as it breaks things wherever */
  word-break: break-all;
  /* Instead use this non-standard one: */
  word-break: break-word;

  /* Adds a hyphen where the word breaks, if supported (No Blink) */
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/ for a more complete answer.

Comment: Looks like `hyphens: auto;` is supported only for English text

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to allow line breaks where they would not otherwise be allowed, but no way in CSS alone. The reason is that CSS works on elements, not characters.

The most robust HTML+CSS way is probably to insert the following after each comma (or other character after which a line break should be allowed):

```
<wbr><a class=wbr></a>
```

with the CSS setting

```
.wbr:after { content: "\00200B"; }
```

This is a tricky issue, see l[ongish explanations](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
div span {
float: left;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: break-word works on spaces, not commas and symbols. I need a solution for bad input, when they don't use spaces after punctuation.

Comment: alos, please add some explanation of how your proposed code can solve the issue